# vuejs button click to next date

Tags: vuejs2

I want to print the date on the input according to the number of days of the button when the buttons are clicked with vue js.
For example: Clicking the 7 Day Button
I want "30.08.2021" to be written.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button @click="getDate(1)" class="btn">TODAY</button>
            <button @click="getDate(7)" class="btn">7 DAY</button>
            <button @click="getDate(14)" class="btn">14 DAY</button>
            <button @click="getDate(30)" class="btn">30 DAY</button>
            <button @click="getDate(45)" class="btn">45 DAY</button>
            <button @click="getDate(60)" class="btn">60 DAY</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input v-model="data.date">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                date: "",
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getDate: function (day) {
            var timeFrom = (day) => {
                var dates = [];
                for (let I = 0; I < Math.abs(day); I++) {
                    dates.push(new Date(new Date().getTime() - ((day >= 0 ? I : (I - I - I)) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toLocaleString());
                }
                return dates;
            }
            return console.log(timeFrom(day));
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: rather than looping, make a date object then +7 days `let now = new Date(); now.setHours(now.getHours() + (7 * 24)); console.log(now.toISOString())`

Comment: only not in the format I want, and I want to enter the value of that button in the history whichever button it is added to
1. BUTTON (TODAY)
2.BUTTON (7 DAYS)
3.BUTTON (15 DAYS)
4.BUTTON (30 DAYS)
5.BUTTON (45 DAYS)
6.BUTTON (60 DAYS)
just come in the date format I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are just creating an array of dates, you need to create one date and then use that value in your template.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button @click="getDate(1)" class="btn">TODAY</button>
      <button @click="getDate(7)" class="btn">7 DAY</button>
      <button @click="getDate(14)" class="btn">14 DAY</button>
      <button @click="getDate(30)" class="btn">30 DAY</button>
      <button @click="getDate(45)" class="btn">45 DAY</button>
      <button @click="getDate(60)" class="btn">60 DAY</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input v-model="data.date" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        date: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getDate(days) {
      const now = new Date();
      const tmpDate = now.setDate(now.getDate() + days);
      const newDate = new Date(tmpDate);
      this.data.date = newDate.toDateString()
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the date format to be written as "DAY MONTH YEAR".
How can I edit it? Can you please fix it so I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: Just change the `.toISOString().slice(0, 10)` to `.toDateString()`